# transitions not update model

Tags: angularjs, transition

I am using transitions to be able to reload data in my view. But it does not work. The model itself loads the data, but they are not visually loaded.

```
var cargarDatos = function(){
    nuevoVehiculo = angular.fromJson(SessionFactory.getDataByKey('nuevoVehiculo'));
    if (nuevoVehiculo) {
            $scope.data.nombre_cliente = nuevoVehiculo.nombre_cliente;
            $scope.data.patente = nuevoVehiculo.patente;
            $scope.data.anio = nuevoVehiculo.anio;
            $scope.data.kilometros = nuevoVehiculo.kilometros;
            $scope.data.marca = nuevoVehiculo.marca;
            $scope.data.modelo = nuevoVehiculo.modelo;
            $scope.data.cilindrada = nuevoVehiculo.cilindrada;
            $scope.data.telefono = nuevoVehiculo.telefono_cliente;
    }
    console.log($scope.data);
}

$transitions.onSuccess({ from: 'trabajos/nuevo_trabajo' }, (trans) => {
    cargarDatos();
});
```

And this I receive, therefore the model if it is loaded :

> {nombre_cliente: "22222", patente: "fgrt22", anio: 2222, kilometros: 2222, marca: "2222", …}

HTML code

```
    <form name="nuevoVehiculoForm" data-ng-submit="nuevoVehiculo()">
    <div layout layout-sm="column">
        <md-input-container flex class="input-form-custom">
            <label>Patente</label>
            <input required name="patente" ng-model="data.patente" ng-pattern="/^((([a-z]|[A-Z]){2}[0-9]{4})|(([a-z]|[A-Z]){4}[0-9]{2}))$/" maxlength="6">
            <div ng-messages="nuevoVehiculoForm.patente.$error">
                <div ng-message="required">Patente es obligatoria.</div>
                <div ng-message="pattern">Patente inválida.</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container flex class="input-form-custom">
            <label>Año</label>
            <input required name="anio" ng-model="data.anio" type="number">
            <div ng-messages="nuevoVehiculoForm.anio.$error">
                <div ng-message="required">Debe ingresar un Año.</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container flex class="input-form-custom">
            <label>KM</label>
            <input required name="kilometros" ng-model="data.kilometros" type="number">
            <div ng-messages="nuevoVehiculoForm.kilometros.$error">
                <div ng-message="required">Debe ingresar un Kilometraje.</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
    <div layout layout-sm="column">
        <md-input-container flex class="input-form-custom">
            <label>Marca</label>
            <input required name="marca" ng-model="data.marca">
            <div ng-messages="nuevoVehiculoForm.marca.$error">
                <div ng-message="required">Debe ingresar Marca.</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container flex class="input-form-custom">
            <label>Modelo</label>
            <input required name="modelo" ng-model="data.modelo" type="text">
            <div ng-messages="nuevoVehiculoForm.modelo.$error">
                <div ng-message="required">Debe ingresar Modelo.</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container flex class="input-form-custom">
            <label>Cilindrada</label>
            <input required name="cilindrada" ng-model="data.cilindrada" type="number">
            <div ng-messages="nuevoVehiculoForm.cilindrada.$error">
                <div ng-message="required">Debe ingresar Cilindrada</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
    <div layout layout-sm="column">
        <md-input-container flex class="input-form-custom">
            <label>Nombre completo</label>
            <input type="text" required name="nombre_cliente" ng-model="data.nombre_cliente" columns="1" md-maxlength="150"></input>
            <div ng-messages="nuevoVehiculoForm.nombre_cliente.$error">
                <div ng-message="required">Nombre completo es obligatorio.</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container flex class="input-form-custom">
            <label>Telefono</label>
            <input ng-pattern="/^([0-9]*)?$/" minlength="11" maxlength="11" required name="telefono" ng-model="data.telefono" type="text">
            <div ng-messages="nuevoVehiculoForm.telefono.$error">
                <div ng-message="required">Teléfono es obligatorio</div>
                <div ng-message="minlength">Teléfono debe tener 11 caracteres.</div>
                <div ng-message="maxlength">Teléfono debe tener 11 caracteres.</div>
                <div ng-message="pattern">Teléfono debe ser numérico</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
    <center>
        <button ng-disabled="!canSubmit()" type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="ingresarNuevoVehiculo()">Ingresar</button>
    </center>
</form>
```

Controller

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('NuevoVehiculoCtrl', ['$scope','$q', 'SessionFactory', 'VehiculosDataService', '$state', '$rootScope', '$transitions', NuevoVehiculoCtrl])

function NuevoVehiculoCtrl($scope, $q, SessionFactory, VehiculosDataService, $state, $rootScope, $transitions) {
    var nuevoVehiculo;

    $scope.data = {
        nombre_cliente: '',
        patente: '',
        anio: '',
        kilometros: '',
        marca: '',
        modelo: '',
        cilindrada: '',
        telefono: ''
    };
};
```

Comment: you should also provide the html code

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi update!

Comment: I guess you have a reference error here. Do you have your `data` object defined in your controller like this: `$scope.data = {}` ? If not, declare it somewhere at the start of your controller.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi $scope.data is defined! :/

Comment: show us where is it

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi update question!

Comment: you should try using `angular.copy` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) for every assignment. Example of usage: `angular.copy(nuevoVehiculo.nombre_cliente, $scope.data.nombre_cliente);`

Comment: thanks, but it does not work either :(